# This code doesn't work// The CSS positioning is driving me crazy. It's never this difficult

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a specific feature in my website that has complicated things ever since it has been inserted. I have now stripped everything away from my website so that it is bare bones. Could you please visit it here to see what I am trying to describe below... http://www.banterbombgames.co.nf/

I have a navigation bar with an animated slider, it works but not like its supposed to. Here are the two issues I would like help with please...

1. The main div called container has the line `margin:auto` in the CSS and it works perfectly by centring the div for me. As soon as I inserted the navigation bar, it now only floats to the left.
2. How do I get the slider to sit back where it is supposed to. Visit this website to see where the slider normally sits so that you know where I want it on my website. http://jsfiddle.net/helpmuchappreciated/Lym2wLLb/1/ .
   Because the CSS sets the slider to `position:absolute` it's still not sitting where I want it. I HAVE TRIED EVERYTHING, I have tried `position:absolute`, `position:relative`, `position:fixed`, `position:inherit`, `position:static` etc.

You're help would be much appreciated!
PS: Feel free to inspect element and edit the code and send it back to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.container` div now floats to the left because you've added:

```
 div {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;     
}
```

That makes every div in your website to be floated to the left. Just add this to the CSS:

```
  .container{
    height:1000px;
    width:960px;
    background-color:#1f487c;
    margin:auto;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
```

As for the second question, you need to add

```
position:relative;
```

to your `.navigation` class in order for your slider to be positioned absolutely in relation to the parent div.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, will try now. @José Tomás Tocino

Comment: This should do it. You made still have to tweak the position of the vertical dividers but you should definitely be "there" with the above adjustments.

Comment: How would I vertically centre the text? @José Tomás Tocino